# which is best IDE to develop apps in react native?

Tags: ide, react-native

I am learning react native , please suggest  me IDE for developing android apps in react native? I am familiar  with native app development and using Android studio for native apps

Answer (score 0):

I think the general preference would be [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com).